# Is there a way to change the searchbox text on Mysite - SP2010?

Tags: my-site, navigation, custom

We have a requirement to change the text in the search textbox on Mysite on the SharePoint 2010 environment. The default search text is “Find People”, it  should be modified to "Search People".

For now we're using a delegate control to insert a startup Javascript (this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript) on the page which changes the text once the page is done loading.

Is there a way or a control to change the search text on pageload? If so, how to do that? By the way, which control renders this? Is it from "MySiteTopNavigation.ascx"?

Comment: found an article - http://weshackett.com/2011/02/sp2010-mysites-part-three-branding/ will give a try..

Answer (score 2):

It's an old post, but yes, "MySiteTopNavigation.ascx" is the place where you can change it (/14/TEMPLATE/CONTROLTEMPLATES). Search for "PeopleSearchBoxEx" and change the parameter "QueryPromptString"

Or you can change the resources file in the virtual directory folder of your web application "sps.en-US.resx e.g. Look for "MySiteTopNav_PeopleSearch_Text" and change the value.